# How to replace the contents of the current buffer with the contents of a file?

Tags: vim

I have an external script that takes a Javascript file and automatically fixes some style issues, I want to apply it to the current buffer right before writing (`BufWritePre,FileWritePre`).

So my idea is to:

- `w /tmp/foo` Write the current buffer contents to a temporary file
- `silent !fixStyle /tmp/foo` Run the script on that file.
- Replace the contents of the current buffer with the contents of `/tmp/foo`

The thing is that I don't know how to do the third step.

Comment: Is there a particular reason for not using that program as a filter (`:%!fixStyle`)?

Comment: the script does not output anything, it only modifies the file in place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way is deleting current contents (`1,$d`, i.e., delete between line 1 and last line), and read in the target file starting from line 0 (before line 1 so that there is no blank line):

```
:1,$d|0r ~/.hck/input
```

Another way is using a filter (cat in this case) to replace all of the content (`%`) with the output of the filter:

```
:%!cat /tmp/foo
```

Comment: It doesn't :(

It's an external script and I don't have any control over it.

Comment: The second option leaves me with an empty buffer (the script does not output anything to the stdout, it modifies the file)

Comment: Thanks perfect, thanks. I used the second one.

If you don't mind, could you explain each command?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`set autoread`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27autoread%27). It detects when the file has been changed on disk and reloads the current buffer from the file. So you could save the file, run the script and vim will reload the buffer with the change contents.

Autoread's help is copied below

```
                 *'autoread'* *'ar'* *'noautoread'* *'noar'*
'autoread' 'ar'     boolean (default off)
            global or local to buffer |global-local|
            {not in Vi}
    When a file has been detected to have been changed outside of Vim and
    it has not been changed inside of Vim, automatically read it again.
    When the file has been deleted this is not done.  |timestamp|
    If this option has a local value, use this command to switch back to
    using the global value: >
        :set autoread<
```